# PhpStorm не видит свойства в data

Tags: vue.js, typescript, phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как научить видеть переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известная проблема, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-48347](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48347).

Единственное решение - использовать вместо `data()` поля класса, как предложено в https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components